# Append Function not giving desired results in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, nested

the code given below does not give the desired results as specified below. i have tried many permutations without success.

```
posLabels = ['abc', 'def', 'ab3','ab4', 'ab5']
senPosList = [('abc','def','ghi'),('jkl','mno','pqr','123'), 
('stu','vwx')]
senVecList= []
senVec = []
posLabels[0] in senPosList[0]

for x in range(3):
    for i in range(5):
        if posLabels[i] in senPosList[x]:
            senVec.append(1)
        else: 
            senVec.append(0)
    senVecList.append(senVec)
print(senVecList)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I want `senVecList =  [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`

Comment: `posLabels[0] in senPosList[0]` is evaluated but not printed or anything. Is that correct?

Comment: Please [edit] and describe what you're trying to do. I've read the question a few times but I still don't get it. See [ask] for more pointers.

Comment: just do `[[1 if y in x else 0 for y in posLabels] for x in senPosList]`

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are trying to accompish is this

```
posLabels = ['abc', 'def', 'ab3','ab4', 'ab5']
senPosList = [('abc','def','ghi'),('jkl','mno','pqr','123'), ('stu','vwx')]
senVecList= []

for x in range(3):
    senVec = []
    for i in range(5):
        if posLabels[i] in senPosList[x]:
            senVec.append(1)
        else: 
            senVec.append(0)
    senVecList.append(senVec)

print(senVecList)
```

Note we are reassigning an empty list to `senVec` in the outer loop. Otherwise you are appending more values to the same old list which is being appended three times.

Answer (score 1):

This produces the desired output, though I still don't understand the goal.

```
pos_labels = ['abc', 'def', 'ab3', 'ab4', 'ab5']
sen_pos_list = [
    ('abc', 'def', 'ghi'),
    ('jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', '123'),
    ('stu', 'vwx')
    ]

sen_vec_list = [[int(p in s) for p in pos_labels] for s in sen_pos_list]

print(sen_vec_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
posLabels = ['abc', 'def', 'ab3','ab4', 'ab5']
senPosList = [('abc','def','ghi'),('jkl','mno','pqr','123'),('stu','vwx')]
senVecList= []
senVec = []
posLabels[0] in senPosList[0]

for x in senPosList:
    for i in posLabels:
        if i in x:
            senVec.append(1)
        else: 
           senVec.append(0)
    senVecList.append(senVec)
    senVec = [] #add this line to clear the list
print(senVecList)
```

You have to clear the list if not you keep adding to it after every loop.

Comment: This is practically the same as [Boyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56284388/4518341)